# Maven can't find any test

Tags: maven, junit5

I copy pom.xml with a similar project were all ok. Add need dependencies. Also, I add Jupiter with scope "compile" otherwise project doesn't compile. I try to find a solution in similar problems but nothing found.

Env: ubuntu 18, idea 2018.3, openjdk8, maven last version.

I try to change more new or old version junit, surefire plugin and junit-platform-surefire-provider but don't find need combination.

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <junit.api.version>5.4.0</junit.api.version>
    <junit.jupiter.version>5.4.0</junit.jupiter.version>
    <junit.platform.version>1.3.1</junit.platform.version>
    <aspectj.version>1.9.4</aspectj.version>
    <allure.version>2.12.1</allure.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-junit5</artifactId>
        <version>${allure.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                </argLine>
                <systemProperties>
                    <property>
                        <name>junit.jupiter.extensions.autodetection.enabled</name>
                        <value>true</value>
                    </property>
                </systemProperties>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3.2</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST_VERSION</version>
            <configuration>
                <reportVersion>2.4.1</reportVersion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: What is the file name of your Test files?  Do they start or end with `Test`

Answer (score 0):

By default the maven Surefire Plugin expects your tests filenames to match the following conditions:

- `**/Test*.java` - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java
  filenames that start with "Test".
- `**/*Test.java` - includes all of
  its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "Test".
- `**/*Tests.java` - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java
  filenames that end with "Tests".
- `**/*TestCase.java` - includes all
  of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with
  "TestCase".

If you test file names don't match the above criteria you have two options.  First of all modify your test filenames so that they do match the above criteria.  Secondly you can modify the inclusion criteria by configuring the maven-surefire-plugin

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>%regex[.*(Cat|Dog).*Test.*]</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

For more information have a look at [the maven-surefire-plugin documentation](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html).